# PLSQL does not compile when substracting two long variables

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm writing a pretty basic procedure where I need to substract two long variables and assign the value to the other variable. But the code doesn't compile and I am getting hopeless - why is that?

```
create or replace PROCEDURE TrendCalculator(p_id Prodeje.product%TYPE)
AS
  v_week_last Prodeje.WEEK%TYPE;
  v_week_current Prodeje.WEEK%TYPE;
  v_year_last Prodeje.YEAR%TYPE;
  v_year_current Prodeje.YEAR%TYPE;
  v_weekly_sales_last PRODEJE.SALES%TYPE;
  v_weekly_sales_current PRODEJE.SALES%TYPE;
  v_pomocna PRODEJE.SALES%TYPE;

CURSOR c_data IS SELECT WEEK, YEAR, SALES FROM Prodeje WHERE PRODUCT = p_id ORDER BY YEAR, WEEK ASC;
BEGIN
  v_pomocna := 0;
  OPEN c_data;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_data INTO v_week_current, v_year_current, v_weekly_sales_current;
    EXIT WHEN c_data%NOTFOUND;
    IF (v_weekly_sales_last IS NOT NULL) THEN        
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(p_id || ' ' || v_week_current || ' ' || v_year_current || ' ' || v_weekly_sales_current);
      v_pomocna := (v_weekly_sales_current - v_weekly_sales_last);
    END IF;
  v_week_last := v_week_current;
  v_year_last := v_year_current;
  v_weekly_sales_last := v_weekly_sales_current;
  END LOOP;
CLOSE c_data;
END;
```

The Error messages I'm getting are:
Error(19,9): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(19,95): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '-'

And PRODEJE.SALES Datatype is LONG.

Comment: what is the error you are getting??

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include them. I edited them in.

Comment: you may need to provide `Prodeje` column`s `datatype` too..

Comment: PRODEJE.SALES Datatype is LONG.

Comment: OK, I'm dumb - i can't use LONG datatype for this, I thought it is a form of a number. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`v_weekly_sales_last` is not set to anything.  So line 19 evaluates to

```
v_pomocna := (v_weekly_sales_current - );
```

Which seems to be the  cause of your error.